# while applying applyMiddleware(thunk) getting "Cannot call a class as a function" , in react js

Tags: reactjs, redux-thunk

Here is my index.js file code -

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'react-thunk';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import Login from './Components/LoginRegister';

const store= createStore(
        (state = {}) => state, 
        applyMiddleware(thunk)
    );

ReactDOM.render(( 
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
            <Route path="/Loginregister" component={Login} />
        </switch>
      </Router>
    </Provider>  ),
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

as I am passing 'thunk' in 'applyMiddleware' as 'applyMiddleware(thunk)'  then I am getting below error on console  -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
    at _classCallCheck (index.js:15)
    at ReactThunk (index.js:36)
    at applyMiddleware.js:51
    at createStore (createStore.js:65)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap b42575b…:555)
    at fn (bootstrap b42575b…:86)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bootstrap b42575b…:578)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap b42575b…:555)
    at bootstrap b42575b…:578
```

please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're importing

```
import thunk from 'react-thunk';
```

But thunk is from the redux-thunk module.

So you should import

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
```

Moreover I think there will be a problem with your call of "createStore".

createStore takes a reducer (or combined reducers) and possible middleware.

A reducer takes a state and an action and has to return the new state of the store.

```
function reducer(state, action){

  // Switch-Case for action.type
  // Copy the current state and apply changes

  return state;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your problem is obvious from the error. You cannot send a function as a class. in `createStore()` your first argument is a function. It should be the combined reducers you have.

Create a file with the reducers you have, import it to the index file. then do something like

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))
```

Comment: thx for ur quick reply, So,  what comes in rootReducer.js file ? Is "(state = {}) => state" or something else ?

Comment: One more thing, If  I write "applyMiddleware() instead of applyMiddleware(thunk)" then its not showing any error, are you sure is error related our first argument ?

Comment: First, as @Bjoern mentioned, import `thunk` from `redux-thunk`, maybe that's the main problem. You might have installed `react-thunk` instead of `redux-thunk` that's why you haven't got a module error. 
About the rootReducer, reducers take state and action, and returns new state according the action sent to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did, i hope it can help somebody

in **index.js**

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk))

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

in **.store/reducers/rootReducer.js**

```
import authReducer from './authReducer'
import projectReducer from './projectReducer'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  project: projectReducer,
})

export default rootReducer
```

and in **.store/reducers/projectReducer.js**

```
const initState = {
  projects: [
    { id: '1', title: 'help me find peach', content: 'blah blah blah' },
    { id: '2', title: 'collect all the stars', content: 'blah blah blah' },
    { id: '3', title: 'egg hunt with yoshi', content: 'blah blah blah' },
  ],
}

const projectReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CREATE_PROJECT':
      console.log('create project', action.project)
      return state
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default projectReducer
```